# docker tools in visual studio version 16.9.1 ignores port override in docker-compose.vs.debug.yml

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

After I updated my Visual Studio to 16.9.1 (Pro Edition), the port mapping defined in "docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" are not applied any more.

Here is the docker command that VS generates :

```
docker-compose  -f "\src\docker-compose.yml" 
-f "\src\docker-compose.override.yml" 
-f "\src\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" 
-f "\src\docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" -p dockercompose2416442517961025023 --no-ansi build
```

docker-compose.override.yml :

```
myapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:roq
```

docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml :

```
myapi:
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
      - "8002:443"
```

This is part of the config generated in MergedDockerCompose2.cache:

```
image: myapi:dev
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: ' --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages
        --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  "/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/myApi.dll"'
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: /bin/sh -c "if PID=$$(pidof
        dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: dotnet
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: /app
    ports:
    - target: 80
    - published: 8001
      target: 80
    - target: 443
    - published: 8002
      target: 443
```

So Visual studio picks a random port which I think comes from lunchSettings.json.

**Update**

Apparently it is bug in Visual studio. I opened a ticket you can access here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/docker-tools-in-visual-studio-version-1691-ignores

and the answer to that :

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Docker-Compose-build-issues-after-update/1371433